# How to find out what happened to my edit?

Tags: discussion

I don't think I know how to properly use the [rejected-edits query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits?UserId=752842).
I recently added an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791372/exception-in-accessing-hadoop-2-3-0-using-classname-and-classpath). (I got the message saying my edit was going to be visible to everyone after peer reviewed, so I am certain it went through the server)

I think it was a good edit, I gathered information from the user and internet to phrase better the problem, I also added the `HDFS` tag. I checked later and my edit didn't take effect, and also apparently someone else had edited the question adding the tag.

I wanted to check why my edit was rejected, I try to do responsible and thorough edits, but I am still learning. However I can't find my edit on the rejected edits query.

**Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong when looking for my rejected edits?
And maybe also help me understand why it was rejected?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see your suggested edits here:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/752842/dzyann?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Apparently, your [suggestion was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8477164) because another user with >2k rep edited the post while yours was pending.

That said, your suggestion added a bit of fluff to the post (*"What am I doing wrong?"*), and other new information. Personally, I'd have rejected your suggestion as well.

Comment: I added the information from the chat I had with the OP on the comments, is that something we are not supposed to do?

Comment: Ah, I see. That isn't immediately obvious from the edit reason / message. You can always add information that the OP provided, to a post. Don't add fluff like _"Thanks"_ etc, though.

Comment: In my edit reason I put "Updated question body with information from comments and rephrased it to make it more clear. Added HDFS tag." How would you suggest I phrase it so it doesn't get rejected on the future? Also I added "What am I doing wrong?" Because there was not a clear question on the post, what would you suggest I do about that? Should I write instead "why am I getting this exception?" or that is not required either?

Comment: My apologies, I completely overlooked the edit reason. There wasn't anything wrong with that, my bad. I simply wouldn't have added _"What am I doing wrong?"_. You can edit it again.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it without adding the "What am doing wrong?" Part, thanks.

Comment: Also I don't mind too much the edit-reject per se, I just felt it was a pity I took the time to get that information from the OP and when they edited it, they removed it all.

Comment: Yea, that can happen at times, the other user doesn't appear to have been paying attention.